# Two computers trying to access a excel file in a third computer (server) to write. Problems with the method

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a POS system for a friend. The POS system is a excel workbook that runs in a desktop computer with a touchscreen. For every sale it accesses a file in the server called products.xlms were I update products quantities.

The problem arises when a second terminal tries to access (to write) the same file at the same time in the server, because if the first computer is alreday using the file, the second computer will open it in Read only mode.

I thought I made a walkaround usign the following function that I found here at stackoverflow:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:     IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:    IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

This function opens the file to check if is being used, and closes returning an Error. Depending the Error number we are able to know if its open or not.

Then I call the function whenever I want to open the file, and it will wait a second and try again if the file is open already:

```
Check:
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("PATH\products.xlsx")
If Ret = True Then
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    GoTo Check
End If
Workbooks.Open("PATH\products.xlsx")
```

However, It doesn't work for me like this because interactions are pretty quick and the best way to show it is to explain the problematic scenario:

- Terminal 1 checks if file is open: Opens file, closes, no error then variable = False. Then opens the file (2nd time) to work with.
- If terminal 2 opens the file just when terminal 1 closed it for the first time, BUM, I have a problem beacuse it will think is unused (and thats true! It was actually unused in that fraction of time), and proceed to open it again (In Read only Mode cause is actually being used).

Hope is clear, I will try to clarify if not.
Any suggestion, workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Excel is a single-user spreadsheet. Stop trying to use it as a multi-user database. Use a proper database, and problem solved.

Comment: Yeah well, thanks for the comment. But the reality is other and I'm looking for a method that helps me walk around this situation. We all know this is not the proper way, Mark Butler already pointed that out in an answer, but it is what it is. If you want to collaborate, you are welcome. If not, thanks for the suggestion, have a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year and keep walking :)

Comment: Is like trying to loose a nut with some Pliers. Is not the proper tool, but you can do the job if you really (and urgently) need to. We'll this is that kind of situation...

Comment: The reality is that you chose to try to use the wrong tool for the job, not us, and now you want to try to cobble a fix to a problem that should never have existed in the first place. As far as the rest of your comment, you don't get to choose who gets to comment or answer here; by posting it you made it open to all. If you don't want to hear comments, don't post here.

Comment: Oh yeah, I do want to hear comments! I love comments, that why I'm posting here. I just was saying Merry Christmas to you If that was going to be your only contribution to this post :) Ah, and a Happy New Year too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should note that I agree with Mark Butler; you're definitely making this hard on yourself by using Excel as the "database". However, what's done is done, so here's what I would try...

```
Sub YourSub()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim YourFile As String

    'Note the ~$ in front of the file name
    YourFile = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\~$Book1.xlsx"
    Do While IsFileOpen(YourFile)
    Loop

    'File should be available to you now
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Replace(YourFile, "~$", ""), ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False)

End Sub
Function IsFileOpen(fPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FileExists(fPath) Then
        IsFileOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

The logic behind this code is that when another user has an Excel file open, Excel creates a 'lock file' with the ~$ prefix. This code checks for whether that lock file exists and if it doesn't it opens the file. This will be far more efficient than the workaround you posted which has to open the entire file each time it needs to check whether the file is in use (not a big deal now, but when you have thousands of rows of data it becomes a much bigger deal).

However, big caveat here, sometimes lock files won't be deleted after the file is closed. In a situation like that, your application(s) would enter an infinite loop since the lock file would perpetually exist. One way to avoid this would be to add some sort of counter so that once the loop hit the count maximum you set (e.g. 100000) it would open the file anyway and check for read only that way.

Another option would be to create a text file with your code immediately before you open the Excel file. Then when you're finished with Excel you delete the text file (basically emulating the 'lock file' I mentioned earlier). This would still be efficient and wouldn't rely on an Excel lock file. To do this try this code:

```
Sub YourSub()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim CheckFile As String
    Dim YourFile As String

    CheckFile = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\OpenCheck.txt"
    Do While IsFileOpen(CheckFile)
    Loop

    'File should be available to you now
    YourFile = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\YourFile.xlsx"

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(YourFile, ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False)
    'And then when you're done with the excel file
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Kill CheckFile   
End Sub
Function IsFileOpen(fPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim FSO As Object ' FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As Object ' TextStream

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FileExists(fPath) Then
        IsFileOpen = True
    Else
        On Error GoTo AlreadyCreated
        Set TS = FSO.CreateTextFile(Filename:=fPath, overwrite:=False)
        TS.Close
    End If
ExitFunc:
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

AlreadyCreated:
    IsFileOpen = True
    Resume ExitFunc
End Function
```

Obviously the text file would have to be saved to your server. I don't have any means right now to test this approach, but as far as I know it should work well.

Comment: Sounds like a really clever walk around! Thanks for the contribution. Gonna try it and comment back.

Comment: Although this is the best answer I got so far, when I tested with two computers in a LAN trying to interact with YorFile.xlsx at the same time (and by this I mean shooting the script on both at the exact same time) I get a "the file is being used. Open as Read-Only?" prompt in excel on one of the computers. If there is a minimal time difference on when I shoot the scripts on both computers this won't happen. I guess as you all told me already, this is because I'am using excel for something that is not made to. Oh well, will have to deal with this situation and hope it happens the less posible.

Comment: @Gonzo See my modified code (second example). If we specify that the existing text file cannot be overwritten, then we can handle the error if both computers run the script at the same time. Logically, one of them will have to create the text file first, so this should avoid instances where when they both don't find a text file that exists already.

Comment: Thanks men. It works and is really efficient. Merry Christmas and the best to you and this community in 2016 :)

Answer (score 4):

*Suggestion:* Don't use Excel for multi-user scenarios. In fact, don't use Excel for anything except spreadsheets. It's a fantastic spreadsheet application and not much good when forced to do anything much else; database applications, POS systems etc. are not what it was designed for. Square pegs, round holes and all that.

If you are keen to stick with MS Office, why not use Access for this?

Create a front-end app which runs on each of the touchscreen terminals, and connect it to a back-end database which is stored centrally. This will save you so much headache in the future.

Comment: Hello Mark, Very True what you are saying. But late for me now. This POS has to run on a Non-Profit organization on January and despite I know It should be migrated, I have no time to do it now. I will appreciate any workarounds if you have any thought and I will follow your suggestion for next year's event.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never any more success than you with multi-user Excel, beyond 'works some of the time provided no one opens the file too soon after anyone else'.

It is pretty easy to link to Access data from Excel (using Data Sources) which does extend the multi-user capabilities somewhat. How much work would it be for you to keep the Excel front-ends and migrate the data tables into Access?

Comment: Will be happy to do it, not much data tables to migrate, but no Access expertise either! Wouldn't know were to start or how to do it and January is pretty close :/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `Worksbooks.Open` opens the workbook too. You open the workbook in the `IsWorkbookOpen` Function and again to write the actual values. 
You have to put the two things together.

Try to open it via `Workbooks.Open ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False`, that will throw an error like your function, which you can check. Like:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Do
    'Clear existing (old) Error-Code
    Err.Clear
    'Try to open
    Open "Path/test.xlsx" For  Input Lock Read Write As #ff
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
        'Workbook is opened from another client, put Wait-code here
    End If
    'If Workbook is open on this client, Error-code is 0 and the loop exits
Loop Until Err.Number = 0
'Write the Values, use wkb
On Error GoTo Errorhandler 'Its always good to catch Errors in an Errorhandler
'Write the Values, use wkb
```

I can't test the Error-Numbers, so you have to check that for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I first use the function to check, and then I was assuming (wrong) the function value will assure the file wasn't open so I was just opening, no error checks. I like the idea of putting both things toghether, but I'm a bit limited with vba, can you please explain me a bit more your suggestion?

Comment: I added a solution to my post. I removed the Gotos and put it in a Loop, as Goto-Statements lead imho to bad coding patterns. The one and only exception should be error handlers as VBA don't support error-catching in another way.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I like your approach. I managed to make it run an does the job (error number = 1004) but when the file is open by another user it will show an alert saying: ""VAWi_Module.xlsx" is being modified by Windows User. Open as read only?" despite the Notify=:False attribute. And if I add the line Application.Displayalerts=False before it will not work (error = 0 even when the file is open by another user).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove my test path. To stop the Open as ReadOnly alert, you could add `ReadOnly:=false` to the Workbooks.Open method. I will edit my post.

Comment: The pop up will still appear even with the ReadOnly:=False. Im trying to do it with the Open command instead and is looking good: Open ("F:\VaWI\VAWi_Module.xlsx") For Input Lock Read Write As #ff, previously ff = Freefile(). In that case Err.Number is 70

Comment: Like the changes I made to my post? I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. 
Instead of checking first and then opening, I will open the file and then check if it is ReadOnly mode, with the code below:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Check:
'disable alerts to skip the excel message "file been used, Open Read Only?"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open((Config.Range("O2").Value) & "\clientdb.xlsx", Notify:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If wkb.ReadOnly Then
    wkb.Close
    'Wait code here
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    GoTo Check
End If
```

If is ReadOnly it means is open somewhere, then it will wait 1 second and try again, until it opens the file as write enabled.

The user Reen the Winter, who posted an answer has some credit because he help me think.

Thanks you all for the responses.

Comment: This might work but is very poor performance as you are opening and closing the file while checking.